# Error MSB3073 building 4.26 caused by extra quotation mark in UE4.26.2 build from github code

Tags: visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am compiling UE4.26.2 on windows 10 system and I got this error
`Error MSB3073 building 4.26 caused by extra quotation mark`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just delete this directory "Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\VisualStudioDTE" and then rebuild from VS. It build successfully. That fixed it for me, thank you !